# ArgumentError: Wrong Number of Arguments (given 0, expected 1) When trying to pass params to application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, controller

In my application, I'm trying to pass params from my view to my application_controller. The method in the application controller will be only allowing a certain part of the page to be visible if a user is a manager. I've tried this quite a few ways, this is what I have right now after some iterating.

application_controller:

```
def is_manager(manager_param)
  manager_param = params[:manager_param]
  return true if manager_param == "Manager"
end
```

and in my view:

```
<% if signed_in? && is_manager(current_user.user_type) %>
```

Basically what I want to do is perform a check against the user's type, which can be User/Manager/etc, and if they're a manager, then show a certain part of the page. I currently have that functioning for an administrator, like so:

application_controller:

```
def is_admin(userparam)
  return true if userparam == true
end
```

and in the view:

```
<% if signed_in? && is_admin(current_user.admin) %>
# Stuff only displayed for admins here
<% end %>
```

However, the admin check is done against a boolean, which is why it works. The manager one is a string in the database rather than a boolean.

I'm sure this is something dumb and simple so any help would be appreciated! Thanks

EDIT: Full Error Message + Trace

```
ArgumentError in StaticPagesController#dashboard
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

    def is_manager(manager_param)
      manager_param = params[:manager_param]
      return true if manager_param == "Manager"
    end

Full Trace:

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:118:in `is_manager'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:197:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block in halting'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in invoke_before'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: `signed_in?` → `signed_in?(current_user)`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I am pretty sure that it's implemented like this: `def signed_in?; !!current_user; end`

Comment: The signed_in? is not the issue as far as I'm aware, it's the second part that breaks it for the manager.

Comment: Show the full error message, complete with backtrace and whatnot.

Comment: Editing the post now to include the full message

Comment: Do you have [custom] method `params` in your controller?

Comment: Added, I think I'm just not properly passing parameters, a bit of lack of experience with rails. And what do you mean by custom method params?

Comment: @Ant-IWH Is there a definition of method `params` in your controller? If so, show it.

Comment: the only place I use params is where I wrote in my post

Comment: Just remove `manager_param = params[:manager_param]` line and everything should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I figured it out, I derped a bit. 
I was right for everything I was doing, but I was putting the def in the before_action rather than as a helper_method.

Final code:

Application controller:

```
helper_method :is_manager

def is_manager(manager_param)
  return true if manager_param == "Manager"
end
```

View:

```
<% if signed_in? && is_manager(current_user.user_type) %>
```

Comment: This is why providing a [mcve] in a question is very important. We had no chance of guessing this.

Comment: That was my bad, as I've only recently been working heavily in ruby these last couple of months, I did not think to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def is_manager(manager_param)
  "Manager" == manager_param
end
```

What's wrong on your code is that you are passing `current_user.user_type` as `manager_param` and then doing `manager_param = params[:manager_param]` that tries to assign a value to the user type which I think you don't want to do.

Also, you can ignore "return true if" since the condition you are checking actually returns true if true and false if false.

Also, you should move that logic to the user model:

```
def is_manager?
  'Manager' == user_type
end
```

and then your helper could be

```
def is_manager?
  current_user.is_manager?
end
```

and you don't need to pass the current user since already available on that context.

Comment: After trying the first change, I am still receiving the same wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) error. Once I have this sorted out I will be moving it over to the user model properly